# using the "unsupported" raster features of django's gdal lib

Tags: python, django, import, raster, gdal

I've read the [Django GDAL API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/) and it explicitly states that *raster* related features are not supported.  Ok, if that's the case I want to use the *other* gdal library which supports these functions.

So I've installed http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/ as well.

However, django doesn't appear to want me to use that *other* gdal library.
It seems there is some kind of conflict within django.

When in a standard python CLI it imports fine:

```
>>> import osr
>>> from osgeo import osr
>>>
>>> import gdal
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> from django.contrib.gis import gdal
>>> gdal.HAS_GDAL
True
```

But when I try the same thing from the *django shell*, or when trying to run a django management command, I get the Error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

What is the difference between the *django shell* and the *standard python CLI* that DJANGO can't find the DLLs?  Is there something I can do to use the other GDAL so I can import and use the functions I need to create a raster?

Answer (score 1):

In case its helpful, I started working on some packages that make it simpler to integrate raster data in a django project.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-raster/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wms/

See also my answer to a related question

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115330/4287